# Auto login on website, stay logged in, and parse with Jsoup (java)

Tags: java, cookies, jsoup, autologin, webautomation

for the last 3 weeks i was to trying to write a programm, which logs onto a website and loops through the pages to filter specific informations (specifis rows/columns of tables). To be fair, this programm is the reason which i though myself coding (in java). I created some kind of an autofiller, which works, but is very slow, since it has to login for every page again. Therefore i was thinking, why my first (following) program isn't working. For some reason im able to log in, but as soon as i switch from the login page to the specific page (which is only accessable when logged in), i am being redirected to the login page.
For the purpose of this question i created a fake account. Maybe someone can help or tell where, where i can read further into this topic. I guess there is a problem with the cookies, though im not sure.

```
 try {
        String url1 = "https://www.novaragnarok.com/";
        String url2 = "https://www.novaragnarok.com/?module=vending&action=item&id=2499";

        Connection.Response res = Jsoup
            .connect(url1)
            .followRedirects(true)
            .data("username", "stackoverflowww", "password", "stackpw")
            .method(Method.POST)
            .execute();

        Map<String, String> cookies = res.cookies();                    

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url2)
                  .cookies(cookies)
                  .followRedirects(true)
                  .get();

        System.out.println(cookies);            
        System.out.println(doc);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)" +
        " Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36";

public void parseWebsite(){
    try{
        Connection.Response homepage = Jsoup.connect("https://www.novaragnarok.com/").userAgent(USER_AGENT)
                .method(Connection.Method.GET).timeout(6000).execute();

        Connection.Response login = Jsoup.connect("https://www.novaragnarok.com//?module=account&action=login&return_url=")
                .cookies(homepage.cookies()).data("txtbox", "stackoverflowww")
                .data("password", "stackpw").userAgent(USER_AGENT).method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .timeout(6000).execute();

        Connection.Response url2 = Jsoup.connect("https://www.novaragnarok.com/?module=vending&action=item&id=2499")
                .cookies(login.cookies()).userAgent(USER_AGENT).method(Connection.Method.GET).timeout(6000).execute();

     //Your Code here

    }catch (SocketException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (UncheckedIOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
 }
}
```